# how to create a vagrant box which is not already in the list http://www.vagrantbox.es

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I understood vagrant as the virtual box definition language(correct me , if I am wrong)

My initial query is I want to create vagrant box for cent os 7 http://www.centos.org which is not already on the list http://www.vagrantbox.es

How can I do that ?

Can I run a vagrant box created in virtual box as headless (without GUI) ?

My Goal was to create a virtual boxes for production environments for testing purposes (which includes creating a virtual box for redhat, suse and centos).

After some initial research in vagrant, I tried to solve the previous problem by creating vagrant box and use the same settings for different operating systems which will allow me to create my test production systems on the fly.

Can someone correct me if I am thinking in a right way? Is this is the way vagrant used for ?

I realised that http://www.vagrantbox.es list does not contain the all the latest versions of linux distros. Can I create my virtual machine from scratch using vagrant ? If so can, some one tell me how to do it?

I ruled out docker as I need a virtual machine instead of virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Vagrant is not a definition language for VirtualBox specifically. It's a Ruby-based DSL (domain specific language) for describing anything from single VMs to complete multi-VM infrastructures. These "VMs" could be either VirtualBox VMs or VMWare VMs or even cloud based compute instances on Amazon EC2 or Rackspace. The neat thing about Vagrant is that it's plugin system and everything (such as the VM *providers* mentioned above) is a plugin.

But back to the original question: if you look for building your own Vagrant *baseboxes* for any of the *providers* mentioned above the tool of choice is called Packer (it's from the creators of Vagran, too):

- https://packer.io/

If you are looking for examples which you can base upon I would definitely take a look at the boxcutter basesboxes here:

- https://github.com/boxcutter/ (sources)
- https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=boxcutter (hosted boxes)

They have configurable packer templates for various operating systems (and versions). You could for example fork their repo and modify the templates according to your needs.

P.S.: you will probably find the most baseboxes on https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search which is more or less the "official" repo for hosted vagrant boxes

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own base box. This link '[Creating a base box](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/boxes.html)' explains about it. Would suggest to have a look at tools like [Veewee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee) for creating base box.

Seems like you have an application which can be deployed in multiple operating system and you like to automate the environment setup. In that case I would suggest to look into configuration management tools like Puppet, Chef, Salt or Ansible to provision your environment. You can plug them to your Vagrant configuration and Vagrant will use them for provisioning your environment.

Comment: thanks for your inputs :) , will leave this question open for sometime to give others a chance as well.